# Dissalow modification of hidden input when submit

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a question and I don't now how to explain that. So I have a form with a input type =  hidden and a submit button :

```
 <input type="hidden"
   name="{{ form_participate.total_amount.name }}"
   id="{{ form_participate.total_amount.name }}"
   value="{{ form_participate.total_amount.value }}"/>
```

The problem is that when I access with firebug and remove the type = hidden, I put a value, for example 1000, and I do submit this value is inserted in database. I can disallow this option ?

Comment: Short answer is you cant.

Comment: Can you help me please ?

Comment: Short answer: you can't.

Comment: Cookies / Session - short answer - onSubmit - sent it with from or validate it on server side.

Comment: This is literally impossible.

Comment: well. you have to take or write code in backend for validation. never ever trust your client input in browser always check from backend. There are lots of tools for example chrome extension name : postman, used to post form data to a specific url.

Comment: You might want to look at my answer for possible alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

### Answer

You **cannot** prevent temporary user modification of the client-side code (HTML, JavaScript, CSS).

---

### Alternatives

**Alternative #1 - Sanitizing with default values**

You can **sanitize and validate** the value on the server side.

**PHP**

```
<?php
$value = $_REQUEST['myHiddenElement'];

// We make sure $value is a number and it its value is between 0 and 100
if(!is_numeric($value) || $value < 0 || $value > 100) {
    // If the value is invalid, we overwrite it with a default value.
    // This way, we're sure only valid values are sent to the server.
    $value = 0; 
}
?>
```

---

**Alternative #2 - Getting back to the user**

You can also show an error message if the value is not valid

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$value = $_REQUEST['myHiddenElement']

if(!is_numeric($value)) {
    if(!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }
    $_SESSION['error'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['error_message'] = "The value contained in [whatever input] is not valid.";
    header('Location: myForm.php'); // This goes back to the form.
}
?>
```

in myForm.php:

```
<?php 
session_start();
// We show a custom error message only if the sesison variable "error" is set.
if(isset($_SESSION['error'])){
    echo '<div class="errorMessage">'.$_SESSION['error_message'].'</div>'; // Shows the message to the user.
    
    unset($_SESSION['error']); // unset() destroys the variables.
    unset($_SESSION['error_message']);
}
?>
```